# Use systemd watchdog support to restart application

Tags: centos, systemd, systemd-journald

I have a simple `systemd` service unit to restart my `python` script on unconditional exits so defined `Restart=always` in the service definition. I just want to absolutely make sure even if the script hangs in some way, I can restart it by enabling the `WatchdogSec=` variable in the unit file.

My problem is the [official docs for systemd's journal](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journald.conf.html) does not explain it clearly.

Quoting from the same page,

> `WatchdogSec=`
>
> Configures the watchdog timeout for a service. The watchdog is activated when the start-up is completed. The service must call `sd_notify(3)` regularly with `"WATCHDOG=1"` (i.e. the "keep-alive ping").

The part that is unclear is, will the **service** itself take care of maintaining the pings with the watchdog service (or) the application it is running (in my case - Python script) needs to maintain the ping by updating the environment variable mentioned.

My simple service definition

```
[Unit]
Description=dev-Status: Computes RF device availability status
           
[Service]
Type=simple

EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/db_EndPoint
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /opt/foobar/foobar.py
RestartSec=10
Restart=always
         
[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

So to this service file if I just add the below line, would it restart my script automatically?

```
WatchdogSec=30s
```

Comment: Check out the original description [here](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/watchdog.html) and the
[sd_notify](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd_notify.html) man page.

Comment: @meuh : Forgive my ignorance on the subject. Could you post an answer on what you are referring here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To "pat" or ping the watchdog, you can use the python [systemd](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/systemd/) package to send the notification:

```
from systemd.daemon import notify, Notification
notify(Notification.WATCHDOG)
```

Comment: It worked real fine! Appreciate it, but can you point me what are the differences between these two similar python modules, the one you shared for [systemd](https://github.com/mosquito/python-systemd) and [python-systemd](https://github.com/systemd/python-systemd)? They seem to have similar APIs built-in

Comment: The [mosquito](https://github.com/mosquito/python-systemd) version uses [Cython](http://cython.org/) to generate the binding, whereas the [systemd](https://github.com/systemd/python-systemd) version uses a CPython C module.

Comment: FWIW `python-systemd` this didn't work for me on Raspberry Pi OS; had to use ([`sdnotify`](https://github.com/bb4242/sdnotify))